# Cross Browser logic to process ActiveX Control file i.e. .ocx file

Tags: javascript, html, css, activex

In Javascript we have a code to use/process ActiveX Control (.ocx) file using `<Object classid=""/>`. We place registry `classid` value in the `classid` attribute of the object tag. Through which javascript is able to find the ActiveXControl and processing it.

But the problem is it is working only in IE but not in chrome.

Please help me to develop cross-browser logic to process ActiveX Control.

Comment: You can get it to work in any browser ... as long as it's internet explorer ... activeX is a Microsoft ONLY "feature" -